# error in Huber regressor sklearn Error: The 'max_iter' parameter of HuberRegressor must be an int

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, linear-regression, forecasting

I am running a forecasting algorithm and suddenly today my algorithm is throwing an error

```
sklearn.utils._param_validation.InvalidParameterError: The 'max_iter' parameter of HuberRegressor must be an int in the range [0, inf). Got 279170.46874829195 instead.
```

I have no idea what went wrong as the script was working continuously since 2 weeks.

my code block is below

```
# Split the data into training and test sets
X_train = X[:-17]
X_test = X[-17:-1]
y_train = y[:-17]
y_test = y[-17:-1]

# Define hyperparameter distributions for random search
param_dist = {'epsilon': truncnorm(1.10, 2.10, loc=1.5, scale=0.2)
                  , 'max_iter': uniform(loc=100000, scale=400000)
                  , 'alpha': uniform(loc=0.0001, scale=0.01)
                  , 'tol': [0.01, 0.00001,0.001,0.0001]
                  }

# Initialize a list to store the best models
best_models = []

# Run random search on the Huber Regressor to find the best model
huber = HuberRegressor()
rand = RandomizedSearchCV(huber, param_distributions=param_dist, n_iter=100, cv=3, scoring='r2', random_state=0)
rand.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Store the best model found in the list of best models
best_model = rand.best_estimator_
best_models.append(best_model)


# Make predictions on the test data
y_pred = best_model.predict(X_test)

# Calculate the evaluation metrics
mae = mean_absolute_error(y_test, y_pred)
mse = mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred)
mape = mean_absolute_percentage_error(y_test, y_pred)
r2 = r2_score(y_test, y_pred)
```

please share some insights. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it is due to the floating point issues in the line `'max_iter': uniform(loc=100000, scale=400000)` of scipy. Can you try `'max_iter': list(range(100000, 400000))` instead?